# Raise an error inside a generator if no data has been yielded

Tags: python, generator

I want to raise an error inside a generator if no `yield` has happened.
Below is a very simplified example of my issue:

```
def test1():
  for i in range(1, 28):
    if i % 5 == 0:
      yield str(i)
  raise CustomEXception

def test2(x):
  for i in range(1, 38):
    if i % x == 0:
      yield str(i)
  raise CustomEXception
   
a = test1()
b = test2()
```

The `test1` and `test2` in reality are looping through data, search for matches, manipulate the data and `yield`. If no data is yielded, an error is raised.

```
for w,q in itertools.products(a, b):
   try:
     print(w + q)
     # do some more operation with w, q
   except CustomException:
     # do some more checking
```

The results from the generators are used to create a Cartesian product.

The problem is that this doesn't work, the exception is raised, with nothing yielded before.

Comment: Perhaps you could update your question with some code which actually demonstrates the issue. There are lots of problems as it stands which are not related to the question.

Comment: @quamrana the real code is the same a for loop, an yield if match, raise at the end; the code in the for is more complex and longer; but the process is the same, the issue is the same.

Comment: Your functions as they stand will always raise an exception at the end. This will defeat `itertools.product()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also you must make sure your functions are only going to `raise` an exception if there have been no `yields`

```py
def test2(x):
    fail = True
    for i in range(1,38):
        if i % x == 0:
            fail = False  
            yield str(i)
    if fail:
        raise ValueError
```

This way, if there are one or more `yields` then no exceptions are raised and `product` will produce its own generator.

Comment: works, the only disadvantage is that every time the condition is matched inside for, fail get the same value.

Comment: That’s what I wanted. So what is the disadvantage?

Comment: if is already false, it is assign again to false, if the condition match multiple times; but is ok, I have no better solution; thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since your exception is raised by the `product` call which exhausts the iterators, you have to structure it differently:

```
try:
    for w, q in itertools.products(a, b):
        print(w + q)
        # do some more operation with w, q
except CustomException:
    # do some more checking
```

Notice that now, `products(a,b)` is within the `try`-block. The loop body itself only ever processes `w,q` **after** it is handed the execution flow from the generator upon a **successful** yield.

Comment: I tested and is not working, it jumps directly to the except without returning/yielding any value

Comment: You write your generator is only raising the exception if no values are yielded. So this seems the expected outcome.

Comment: because is at the end of code the exception is raise everytime, because yield doesn't get out of function; not to raise or not before results is what I want.